Schedule programmatically ASIC mining
i'm looking to get into ASIC mining buying something around 1kW of power.
I have photovoltaic panels at home and during the day I have excessive power I can use to mine. I'm not set on a specific company but goldshell seems to have some interesting options.
Is it possible to control the ASIC miners programmatically and set the to stop and start at given day times?
I'm fine with using a PC or a raspberry PI to control it but online I cannot find any reference to APIs to control them remotely (if not using the web interfaces).
Has somebody do it before? can you point me to some source explaining more?
